# How to Restore/Reset Unity after Messing up with Unity Tweak tool?? [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS]

Tags: unity, 16.04, unity-dash, unity-tweak-tool

So I had my perfect desktop and everything was running smooth, and then I decided to press one button on the Unity-Tweak-Tool Software and Booom, my unity-panel is gone, I can't access unity-dash and the themes don't apply correctly.

[image]

The button that messed up everything [Restore Defaults]:

[image: Image2]

My Desktop now (no Unity-Panel, Can't access Unity Dash, theme decorations to windows borders doesn't work):

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: I just had the exact same problem... very frustrating. I'm still trying to figure out how to restore it.

Answer (score 8):

I've just got the exact same problem and solved it by opening a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T and typing these commands:

```
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

This will make unity-tweak-tool reset every setting to the default value, then reset the compiz configuration, and finally restart unity.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like maybe CCSM disabled unity-plugin. Here how to enable it:

In terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
ccsm
```

Look for the plugin unity. Enable it.

Comment: The question explains the user of Unity Tweak Tool, **not** CCSM - which might not even be installed (it wasn't in my case).

Comment: @Valorin, ccsm does not have to be installed for unity compiz to function.  Also doing something in tweak tool CAN make the unity compiz deactivate.. This have helped me many times.. Why the downvote? Also if it's not installed, just install it. Will update my post.