# Launcher and Panel disappeared on 16.04 after July 20/2016 update

Tags: 16.04, launcher, panel

After installing regular system updates yesterday and rebooting, suddenly Launcher and menu bar are missing, Tried looking for answers under similarly titled threads but nothing I've tried seems to help. Tried disabling and re-enabling unity in Compiz. I'm really new to Linux and not very familiar with it yet. I am trying to learn but have not had any luck with everything I've tried that was suggested in the other threads.

The only way I'm able to do anything right now is that I can make the launcher and menu bar reappear (temporarily) when I type `unity --debug` into the terminal which results in this:

```
~$ unity --debug
unity-panel-service stop/waiting
unity7 stop/waiting
unity-panel-service start/running, process 5114
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
[New Thread 0x7ffff3637700 (LWP 5233)]
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
[New Thread 0x7fffeb20e700 (LWP 5234)]
[New Thread 0x7fffeaa0d700 (LWP 5235)]
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : unity
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: opengl
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
[New Thread 0x7fffe1dfc700 (LWP 5236)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe15fb700 (LWP 5237)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe0dfa700 (LWP 5238)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd962c700 (LWP 5239)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd8e2b700 (LWP 5240)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd862a700 (LWP 5241)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd7e29700 (LWP 5242)]
[New Thread 0x7fffd7628700 (LWP 5243)]
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: place
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: place
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: wall
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: wall
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: session
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: copytex
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: copytex
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: grid
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: grid
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: mousepoll
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: mousepoll
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: vpswitch
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: vpswitch
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: compiztoolbox
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: compiztoolbox
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: resize
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: resize
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: imgpng
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: imgpng
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: regex
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: regex
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: move
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: move
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: commands
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: commands
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: snap
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: snap
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: animation
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: animation
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: fade
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: fade
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: workarounds
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: workarounds
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: expo
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: expo
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: scale
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: scale
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ezoom
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ezoom
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unityshell
/usr/bin/compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unityshell
[New Thread 0x7fffc3eef700 (LWP 5253)]
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:08 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'org.gnome.Shell' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.debug.interface DebugDBusInterface.cpp:217 Unable to load entry point in libxpathselect: libxpathselect.so.1.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory -- full D-Bus introspection will not be available
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 xim.controller XIMController.cpp:103 IBus natively supported.
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.dash.gsettingsscopereader GSettingsScopes.cpp:108 Error fetching protocol metadata for scope: social.scope : Valid key file could not be found in search dirs
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Dash' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
[New Thread 0x7fffc2c56700 (LWP 5257)]
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Session' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
[Thread 0x7fffc2c56700 (LWP 5257) exited]
ERROR 2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:538 DBus name lost 'org.gnome.Shell'
ERROR 2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:538 DBus name lost 'com.canonical.Unity'
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:108 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:108 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:108 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:108 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:108 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:108 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:108 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:108 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:108 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
WARN  2016-07-21 12:19:09 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:108 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it
[Thread 0x7fffc3eef700 (LWP 5253) exited]
[New Thread 0x7fffc3eef700 (LWP 5295)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc2c56700 (LWP 5296)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc1a01700 (LWP 5297)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc1200700 (LWP 5298)]
[New Thread 0x7fffc09ff700 (LWP 5299)]
[New Thread 0x7fffabfff700 (LWP 5300)]
[Thread 0x7fffc1a01700 (LWP 5297) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc1200700 (LWP 5298) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffabfff700 (LWP 5300) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc2c56700 (LWP 5296) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc09ff700 (LWP 5299) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffc3eef700 (LWP 5295) exited]
```

Comment: Did you try this? http://askubuntu.com/a/797781/360794

Comment: Try to remove the `~/.config/compiz-1` directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 1):

Removing the compiz config directory worked as per `@zerkms` suggestion. thank you!

In partiular, I used

```
mv ~/.config/compiz-1 ~/Desktop
```

to move it to the desktop in case it didn't work, that way it wouldn't be straight up deleted, and I could move it back if it wasn't the culprit. After moving the directory, everything went back to normal after a reboot.

Thanks again for answers guys, still a n00b but every little thing I learn helps!

Comment: btw, something is messed up, after removing this, managed to get launcher back, just small issue: my dual screen setup in no more able to hide second launcher (i usually keep one launcher for two screens, i wonder if that's what got other people here)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but removing compiz-1 directory didn't solve the issue. This works but not completely:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid compiz --replace
```