# Touchscreen Unity MT Grab Handles doesn't work after resume

Tags: unity, suspend, multi-touch, touchscreen

Under 16.10 I used to use the Unity MT Grab Handles with my touchscreen laptop to perform various three finger actions (resize, move, etc). Since I installed 17.04 I cannot get this to show up after a resume.

I have installed the Compiz Setting Manager CCSM and selected the Unity MT Grab Handles plugin. It works fine until I send my laptop to sleep and resume it (everytime I close and reopen the lid).

The only thing else I did was to take Gnome Desktop for a spin after installing 17.04 but I reverted back to Unity fairly quickly. I'm guessing there is something left over from that experiment that is causing this?

How can I go about troubleshooting? The basic touchscreen clicking works, but not the Unity MT Grab Handles. As far as I know this should, *Just Work (tm)*, for multitouch devices like mine as it used to before the upgrade.

Edit: I've tried the suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769384/how-to-restore-reset-unity-after-messing-up-with-unity-tweak-tool-ubuntu-16-0#answer-797781) to reset Unity, still not working after resume.

Dell Insprion 15 7000 series
Ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst not a complete answer I did manage to solve this without a full reinstall..... a fake reinstall. I used the [Resetter](https://github.com/gaining/Resetter) project to roll back and remove all extra packages on my system.

It gave me the option to customise this and by default it will remove your home directory and user account unless you tell it not to. But the end result is pretty close to a fresh install.

I now have my grab handles back!